# Is it possible to "-passthru" to Log file only and not the console when using "Start-Transcript -Path "$LogOutput"

Tags: powershell, logging, copy-item

I have a Powershell script where I want the console to output my custom messages only, but I would like to capture what the command is doing in a log only. Is this possible?

Just to make it clearer with an example below. I want to copy all the Sub Directories and Files as they are in their own directory to a new location:

```
Start-Transcript -Path "$LogOutput" -IncludeInvocationHeader -Append 

 Get-ChildItem -Path "$Source" | Copy-Item -Destination "$Destination" -Exclude "File*.xml" -Force -Recurse -PassThru

Stop-Transcript
```

I then use $? to get the success of the result on the console for my custom messages.

The above shows details I find helpful but it outputs the -PassThru on the console which I do not want to display there. If I don't specify it, it outputs nothing in the Transcript log either.

If I try appending to the copy command `...-PassThru | Out-File -FilePath "$LogOutput" -Append` (*The same Log used for Transcript*) it fails as the log file is locked by the Transcript. Is there a way to make this possible, or will I have to append `...-PassThru | Out-File -FilePath "$LogOutput" -Append` to all my commands individually?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: As an *aside* comment,  filter before the pipeline. I.e: `Get-ChildItem -Exclude`

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, Thanks I made that change now. Is that just more efficient/faster?

Comment: Yes, you always want to filter as far left as possible. Sending anything over to the pipeline slows it down a lot more than you think.